# Span columns with docxTemplate python

Tags: python, jinja2, docx

I'm having trouble trying to fill in a table row by row using DocxTemplate. I'm  only confused on how the template should look like.

This is my python code:

```
from docxtpl import Docxtemplate

doc = DocxTemplate("Template.docx")
context = {}
table_info = [{start: "A", end: "C"}, {start: "B", end: "C"}, {start:"F", end:"L"}, {start:"B", end:"R"}]
context["table_info"] = table_info

doc.render(context)
doc.save("Finish.docx")
```

I want the final result to be in a table like this:

```
| start | end |
|  A    | C   |
|  B    | C   |
|  F    | L   |
|  B    | R   |
```

Would anyone be willing to show me how I can accomplish this? I saw the [dynamic_table_tpl](https://github.com/elapouya/python-docx-template/blob/master/tests/templates/dynamic_table_tpl.docx) example but I wasn't able to wrap my head around what I'm trying to do. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Adapting the code test from https://github.com/elapouya/python-docx-template/blob/master/tests/dynamic_table.py to your need:

```
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate

doc = DocxTemplate('Template.docx')

context = {
    'col_labels' : ['start', 'end'],
    'tbl_contents': [
        {'label': 'black', 'cols': ['A', 'C']},
        {'label': 'black', 'cols': ['B', 'C']},
        {'label': 'black', 'cols': ['F', 'L']},
        {'label': 'black', 'cols': ['B', 'R']},
        ]
}

doc.render(context)
doc.save('Finish.docx')
```

Your build for `context` is using wrong key names.